# QuickFixJ multiple login requests sent(login response treated as request)

Tags: java, authentication, quickfix

I use QuickFixJ, there is only initiator in settings.
I send logon request, receive response but it's treated as a logon request and another logon request is sent.

> toAdmin:FIX.4.4:XXXX->XXXX;m=8=FIX.4.49=7535=A34=249=XXXX52=20130816-11:55:25.26356=XXXX98=0108=10141=Y10=089
>
> FixLog - OUTGOING -
>   8=FIX.4.49=7535=A34=149=XXXX52=20130816-11:55:25.26356=XXXX98=0108=10141=Y10=088
>
> FixLog - INCOMING -
>   8=FIX.4.49=007735=A49=XXXX56=XXXX52=20130816-11:55:25.73934=00000000198=0108=1010=021
>
> FixLog - Inferring ResetSeqNumFlag as sequence number is 1 in response
>   to reset request
>
> FixLog - Logon contains ResetSeqNumFlag=Y, resetting sequence numbers
>   to 1
>
> fromAdmin:FIX.4.4:XXXX->XXXX;m=8=FIX.4.49=7735=A34=00000000149=XXXX52=20130816-11:55:25.73956=XXXX98=0108=1010=181
>
> FixLog - Received logon
>
> toAdmin:FIX.4.4:XXXX->XXXX;m=8=FIX.4.49=7535=A34=149=XXXX52=20130816-11:55:25.90156=XXXX98=0108=60141=Y10=092
>
> FixLog - OUTGOING -
>   8=FIX.4.49=7535=A34=149=XXXX52=20130816-11:55:25.90156=XXXX98=0108=60141=Y10=092
>
> Initiated logon request

Has anybody faced such a problem, any suggestions?

Comment: Let me see your raw message log.

Comment: What exactly do you need? I've put here everything related to FIX since logon request.

Comment: You haven't, actually.  If you use a FileLogFactory, you should have a file that contains all the raw FIX message traffic.  It is the most useful thing you can have for diagnosing problems.  (Also, please replace the field separator characters with something visible, like "|", so we can better tell the fields apart).